# Where to modify the pseudonym used to rate Android apps?

Tags: google-play-store, privacy, app-ratings

I am currently rating android applications that I downloaded with the username `firstname.lastname` where `firstname` and `lastname` are mine.

However, I would like to put a pseudonym on it because my real name reveals to everybody the device I am using, which should be private. Currently, my rating looks like this one:

```
firstname.lastname on May 22, 2012 (Samsung Galaxy S2 with version 1.0)
```

I looked into my public profile of Google+, but I cannot find something which looks like `firstname.lastname`.
I looked on the Google Play website, but I did not find related preferences.

Where can I change this name? Is it in the device itself or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found it. I need to click on "edit/modify" close to the e-mail addresses in the google account setting

https://www.google.com/settings/

Then the hidden nickname option appears.
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you add please a screen?

Answer (score 3):

Change your nickname in your Google account settings.

Comment: Where is this nickname option ?

Answer (score 1):

Now accepted answer is obsolete. Now go to https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info then click "Choose what others see" then you are on "About me" page and in section "Basic info" next to the name is arrow, click it and there you can enter nickname.

But nickname can not be used standalone but only combined with name and surname. Google fail!

Comment: Welcome Mike! I edited your answer just a touch.  Freudian slip? ;)